# Find all unit vectors u in the xy-plane that make an angle of 45 degrees with v = [1,0,1]

Tags: vectors, inner-products

For this question, I started with the dot product of an arbitrary vector u and v:

u•v

```
= ||u|| ||v|| cos(45)
= (1) (√2) (√2/2)
= 1
```

Then I used the u1v1 + ... + u3v3 = 1 property, and then subbed in u1 = 1 - u3 into the ||u|| formula, more subbing... and ended up with a vector all in terms of u3: u = [ 1 - u3 , √(2•u3), u3 ] where 0 <= u3 <= 1 . Is this final answer correct? The answer I was given says that the answer is (cosx , sinx, 0) , but that can't be right since it asks for all vectors unit vectors, and obviously (0, 0, 1) would work.

Comment: All unit vectors in the $xy$ plane take the form $v = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$, so we call $ u = (1,0,1) $ , then we want $ u \cdot v = \| u \| \| v \| \cos 45^\circ $ and this gives $ \cos \theta = 1$, which has only one solution and that is $\theta = 0 $.  Therefore, the only solution is  $v = (1, 0, 0) $

Comment: Every vector on the $xy$-plane has $z$-coordinate $0$.

Comment: In particular, $(0,0,1)$ *doesn't* work, since it isn't in the xy-plane.